# How to install specific pip version with Pip 18.1?

Tags: python, pip

After pip was upgraded to 18.1 the following command doesn't work anymore:

`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O get-pip.py && python /tmp/get-pip.py pip==9.0.1`

Error message is:

```
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-DgcFrM
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-oBsk3Z
Created requirements tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-oBsk3Z'
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-FAvXbK
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-oBsk3Z'
Double requirement given: pip (already in pip==9.0.1, name='pip')
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpq8by8x/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/tmp/tmpq8by8x/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 293, in run
    self.name, wheel_cache
  File "/tmp/tmpq8by8x/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 220, in populate_requirement_set
    requirement_set.add_requirement(req_to_add)
  File "/tmp/tmpq8by8x/pip.zip/pip/_internal/req/req_set.py", line 108, in add_requirement
    % (install_req, existing_req, name)
InstallationError: Double requirement given: pip (already in pip==9.0.1, name='pip')
```

How do I install pip with the new version of get-pip.py ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this very recent [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/issues/37), there is a bug in how `get-pip.py` reads the pip version from the command line, but the ticket describes a workaround involving putting the version constraint in a file:

```
python get-pip.py -c <(echo 'pip==18.0')
```

If you're not using `bash`, then you will need create the file in a separate command and pass that into `get-pip.py`:

```
echo 'pip==18.0' > /tmp/pip-version.txt
python get-pip.py -c /tmp/pip-version.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is another solution that tried it :

```
PIPVERSION=18.1
```

then :

```
curl -o /tmp/get-pip.py -sSL "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py"
```

and to trigger the installation :

```
python /tmp/get-pip.py pip==${PIPVERSION}
```

to verify the pip version : (following the output from my terminal)

```
$ pip --version
$ pip 18.1 from /home/moez/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

if you get the following output when you check the pip version :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

then, open the file /usr/bin/pip and replace the code with this one :

```
from pip import __main__
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(__main__._main())
```